# Removing invalid library references from Eclipse Mars doesnt work

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I cant remove invalid library references from Eclipse - Java Buildpath - Libraries. When I select the non existent lib then all the buttom are stay gray.

Eclipse J2EE Mars.

Thanks in advance.

Cs.

Check this https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD5A59ED0A917DBF!161&authkey=!AFum3a8dZQXuJYk&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Can you add snapshot?, its working for me.

Comment: Maybe you can try removing the library from your `.classpath` file in the project root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reimport user libs in the !right order! in Window - Preferences - Java Buildpath - User Libraries

The proper order is when the wrong references are overwrited with good ones.
xproj: with wrong referenced libs
yproj: -ii- right -ii-

Ok, yproj also must have right prefs for libs as well.